# Map only a set amount of items from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am trying build a small preview section on my websites homepage that shows the first 3 items of the products page where all of the items are,  with a map function that looks like this.

````
{goldendoodles.map((goldendoodles) => (
       
          <Card style={{width: '20rem'}}>
          <img className="cardimage" src={goldendoodles.image} alt={goldendoodles.name} />
          <h1>{goldendoodles.name}</h1>
          <p>{goldendoodles.price}</p>
        
        
        <h1>{goldendoodles.description}</h1>
          </Card>
      ))}
    ```
````

Currently it's mapping all of the items as expected 
I am wondering is there a way to only map a certain amount of the items in the array, instead of the whole thing?
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For first 3 items, you could use `.slice()` ([doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice))

> The `slice()` method returns a shallow copy of a portion of an array into a new array object selected from `start` to `end` (`end` not included) where `start` and `end` represent the index of items in that array

```
{ goldendoodles.slice(0, 3).map((goldendoodles) => (...) }
```

Comment: This worked, thank you for letting me know about a feature that I had forgotten!

Answer (score 1):

Use an Array function like `slice` ([doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)) or `filter` [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Just like map these function return a new array instead of mutating the given one. So you don't have to worry abour state inconsistencies.

```js
goldendoodles.slice(0, 3).map((goldendoodles) => (...)
```

```js
goldendoodles.filter(goldendoodle => /* Your filter function */).map((goldendoodles) => (...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can filter the array down with [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) before using `.map()` as:

```
{
   goldendoodles.filter((_, index) => index < 3)
                .map((goldendoodles) => (
                     <Card style={{width: '20rem'}}>
                          { /* your elements */ }
                     </Card>
                )
}
```

> The `filter()` method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

Based on that you are getting the first 3 items from your array as the following example:

```js
const data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
const result = data.filter((_, index) => index < 3);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution for the first three items:

```
{ goldendoodles.filter((e, i) => i < 3).map(goldendoodle => {} ) }
```

Or you could do it in one step:

```
{ goldendoodles.reduce((a, c, i) => {
  if (i < 3) a[i] = c
  return a
}, []) }
```